# Android ICS spelling error correction causes PopupWindow to crash

Tags: java, android, user-interface, widget

In our application we have a custom popupwindow. It works perfect on 2.2 -> 4.0.3 no hitches. If you misspell a word in ICS in the edit text within the popupwindow and click on it to have android attempt to correct it, the application instantly crashes every time with this exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(13275): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@42929b28 is not valid; is your activity running?
E/AndroidRuntime(13275):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:515)
E/AndroidRuntime(13275):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:279)
E/AndroidRuntime(13275):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:193)
E/AndroidRuntime(13275):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:118)
E/AndroidRuntime(13275):    at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
E/AndroidRuntime(13275):    at android.widget.PopupWindow.invokePopup(PopupWindow.java:988)
E/AndroidRuntime(13275):    at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAtLocation(PopupWindow.java:845)
E/AndroidRuntime(13275):    at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAtLocation(PopupWindow.java:809)
E/AndroidRuntime(13275):    at android.widget.TextView$PinnedPopupWindow.updatePosition(TextView.java:9517)
E/AndroidRuntime(13275):    at android.widget.TextView$PinnedPopupWindow.show(TextView.java:9474)
E/AndroidRuntime(13275):    at android.widget.TextView$SuggestionsPopupWindow.show(TextView.java:9718)
E/AndroidRuntime(13275):    at android.widget.TextView.showSuggestions(TextView.java:10010)
E/AndroidRuntime(13275):    at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:8319)
E/AndroidRuntime(13275):    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:5486)
E/AndroidRuntime(13275):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
E/AndroidRuntime(13275):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1728)
E/AndroidRuntime(13275):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
E/AndroidRuntime(13275):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1728)
E/AndroidRuntime(13275):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
E/AndroidRuntime(13275):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1728)
E/AndroidRuntime(13275):    at android.widget.PopupWindow$PopupViewContainer.dispatchTouchEvent(PopupWindow.java:1576)
E/AndroidRuntime(13275):    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:5662)
E/AndroidRuntime(13275):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:2863)
E/AndroidRuntime(13275):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
E/AndroidRuntime(13275):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(13275):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(13275):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
E/AndroidRuntime(13275):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(13275):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(13275):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
E/AndroidRuntime(13275):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
E/AndroidRuntime(13275):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is the source file where the exception is being thrown from:

http://130.75.2.12/source/xref/android/4.0.3/frameworks-base/core/java/android/view/ViewRootImpl.java

and the line that invariably causes it:

```
res = sWindowSession.add(mWindow, mSeq, mWindowAttributes, getHostVisibility(), mAttachInfo.mContentInsets,mInputChannel);
```

Problem is sWindowSession is an interface for a service and I can't find the service's implementation? (http://130.75.2.12/source/xref/android/4.0.3/frameworks-base/core/java/android/view/IWindowSession.aidl)

Does anyone have any information on the service itself or the reason we're getting an exception here?

Comment: If you run out of other ideas, you might see how minimal an example you could make which would experience this crash.

Comment: From what I have been able to discover, the issue is with any popup window spawning as a child from another popup window.  I was able to get this to occur on a FroYo Galaxy Tab.

Comment: I have the same errors since I updated my Galaxy Note text device from android 2.2 to 4.0.3, both a dropdown spinner and the error message of an editText generate the error while invoking a PopupWindow.

Comment: any updates to this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28007388/android-view-windowmanagerbadtokenexception-list-view-set-text-then-focus could do with some love too