# android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException list view set text then focus

Tags: java, android, listview, exception, user-interface

This is my code:

```
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        LinearLayout viewGroup = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_popup);
        final View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout,viewGroup);

        final PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(GameActivity.this);

        Point popupSize = new Point(getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.popup_width),getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.popup_height));


        popup.setContentView(layout);
        popup.setWidth(popupSize.x);
        popup.setHeight(popupSize.y);
        popup.setFocusable(true);

        File dir = getFilesDir();
        File temp = new File(dir.getPath()+"/temp.prj");
        try {
            if(!temp.exists())temp.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        File[] filesArray = dir.listFiles();
        ArrayList<String> files = new ArrayList<>();

        for(File file:filesArray)
        {
            files.add(file.getName());
        }

        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);

        popup.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, (size.x-popupSize.x)/2, (size.y-popupSize.y)/2);


        ListView listView = (ListView)layout.findViewById(R.id.listViewDir);
        final EditText fileName = (EditText)layout.findViewById(R.id.editTextFilename);

        final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(GameActivity.this,R.layout.list_item, files);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position, long id) {
                final TextView item = (TextView) view;
                fileName.setText(item.getText());
            }
        });
```

The bit that is causing me trouble is:

```
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position, long id) {
                final TextView item = (TextView) view;
                fileName.setText(item.getText());
            }
```

Where after I have clicked on the item in the list view, I then go to click on the filename view and the exception

```
 android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@53668b30 is not valid; is your activity running?
```

is thrown. I have tried running `fileName.setText(item.getText());` on the UI thread, I have tried using `MainActivity.this` (or my variant of it, `GameActivity.this`) in numerous different places. Nothing seems to be working. Does anyone have any idea what's going wrong? All related questions seem to revolve around a Dialog rather than a Popup

---

**UPDATE**

For some unearthly reason, adding `android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"` to the EditText `fileName` in xml stops the exception. I only noticed this after prefixing the items in the listview with a number (which means they don't get spellchecked). It looks like someone else ran into a similar error [Android ICS spelling error correction causes PopupWindow to crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10501984/android-ics-spelling-error-correction-causes-popupwindow-to-crash) and they too do not have an answer